# Streamreader doesn't find the file on some computers

Tags: c#, dll, streamreader

I have made a application in c# wpf .Net 4.5 that is using a c# library dll
assembled in .net 4.0. This dll uses a file that must be in the exe directory.
On all my computers my application works, but when I send this application to some other computers the application will throw my exceptions that is telling me that the dll I am using is not finding the file. I have decompiled the dll and checked out the code but it doesn't change the working directory at any point, However it uses it.

I suspect that this have something to do with the language of the computers but im not sure.

I have set the Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(...) to my exe path in alot of diffrent ways without success.

Does anyone have any clue how to solve this?

Edit: The full auctual error doesnt tell me the path Streamreader looked for the file.
I have used Clickonce deployment but for now I copy the binary folder and I guarantee that the file is in the correct spot.

Comment: Show us a little bit of code. For example,how do you set the path for that file or if it is an executable, how are you starting it. Also..are you using ClickOnce to deploy your app?

Comment: What file? Why do you assume that the file exists? What is the *full* actual error that shows the path the application tried to access? Either you are using a hard-coded path or your installation program fails to copy the file. BTW the default current directory *is* the `.exe`'s directory

Comment: Are you using a shared folder?  Does the folder name start with a drive letter (like f:\) or a network pathname (\\mycomputer)?  Are the credentials  allowing other user to access file?  Can you locate file with Windows Explorer on other PC's.  Can you open the file using Notepad on other computers?

Comment: No shared folder, all folders I have tested the program in have a clean name. I can locate the file yes and its possible to open.

Answer (score 0):

As i suspected this had something to do with the language of the windows.

This line fixed the problems, but it would be nice if someone explained why.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: We can´t explain anything, as you have shown NO code. I forgot my Crystal Ball in the other suit...

Comment: How can i show you code of a dll i haven't written? Only thing i know is that it fails to load a file on some computers?

Comment: Your question said "I have *made* an application"!!